# ng-click not calling the function

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am learning AngularJs and was trying to run a custom directive. I have a button and on click of the button, I need to handle to event inside my controller. I am not getting the function call on `ng-click` directive. I am attaching the `plnkr` link: [Link to plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0S0LDh9Xo8gzDhNvb88H?p=preview)

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module("app", []);

angular.module('app').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  
  $scope.developer={
    name: "Pradeep Kumar L",
    age: 32,
    city: "Bengaluru",
    friends:[
      "Praveen",
      "Kori",
      "Kiran"
      ]
  }
 
 $scope.handleClick = function(){
   developer.rank="friend";
    console.log("button clicked..");
  }

});

angular.module('app').directive('mySimpleDirective', function(){
  return{
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: 'userInfoCard.html'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
  <h4>{{developer.name}}</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <span ng-show='!!developer.age'><h4>User age:  {{developer.age}}</h4></span>
    <h4>User city: {{developer.city}}</h4>
    <h4>Friends</h4>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="friend in developer.friends">
        {{friend}}
        
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-show="!developer.rank">
      Rank: {{developer.rank}}
    </div>
    <div ng-show="!developer.rank">
      <button class="btn btn-success"  ng-click="handleClick(developer)">Click Me</button>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function is triggered but you have a syntax error inside it :

```
 $scope.handleClick = function(){
    $scope.developer.rank="friend";
    console.log("button clicked..");
 };
```

or

Usually, people use the following way when they have to deal with a list of developers, and the function would have been inside a ng-repeat.

```
 $scope.handleClick = function(developer){ //as far as you pass it as argument
    developer.rank="friend";
    console.log("button clicked..");
 };
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/vsRr9CfXxK0HQ7XS5GFe?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. A simple mistake and more than an hour of debugging.

Answer (score 2):

if you switch on console in your plunker you will see an error:

```
ReferenceError: developer is not defined
at Scope.$scope.handleClick (script.js:18)
at $parseFunctionCall (angular.js:12456)
at callback (angular.js:21692)
at Scope.$eval (angular.js:14555)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:14654)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:21697)
at HTMLButtonElement.n.event.dispatch (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3)
at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3)
```

you should add or argument on function or $scope to line script.js:18

Answer (score 1):

When clicking the button, you are passing in `developer` to the `handleClick` function:

```
<button class="btn btn-success"  ng-click="handleClick(developer)">Click Me</button>
```

However, in your javascript, your `handleClick` function does not have `developer` as an argument:

```
$scope.handleClick = function () { // developer is not passed in...
  developer.rank="friend"; // ...so it will be undefined here
  console.log("button clicked..");
}
```

To fix this, your function *should* be:

```
$scope.handleClick = function (developer) { // developer can be passed in...
  developer.rank="friend"; // ...so this WILL work!!
  console.log("button clicked..");
}
```